# Django for multiple db users

Tags: database, django, oracle

We have an ERP system which works with Oracle and we need an Intranet for that. I'd like to do it by Django but Django's authentication system works with its own with a single user or with multiple db's.

My problems are like on following:

- The database has many triggers which has checked database "user". So I can't work with a single user.
- I cannot define a different db for each user.

So is it possible to put a middleware authentication and authorization which works for different logged users?

Comment: I'm finding it a bit difficult to understand your requirements. How do the users differ? There should be a single database (your ERP system), which django can also hook into. You can even tell the models you write for that database to be read only (managed=False in the Meta class). You can also create your own authorization/authentication middleware that looks at a specific table in your ERP system. But what is it exactly that you're trying to do. You need to be more clear with your question.

Comment: Many tables have triggers such as "SELECT seq_ip_list.NEXTVAL INTO recno FROM dual; :NEW.RecNo:= recno; :NEW.recorded_by := SYSDATE;:NEW.record_date := USER;", so the usernames of db for each user is important.

Comment: Oh, there is a database account per user? That seems sort of unusual to me at this point in time. I don't think what you want to do is possible though. Djangos database drivers are configured with username/password in a global settings file - so supplying them at run time from a middleware authentication doesn't seem to me like it'd work. It'd also be lost between requests unless you used memory sessions rather than db sessions. I don't think django is going to be the right choice here.

Comment: The first of all, sorry for my English. "Database account per user" phrase were useful for me to get a remarkable Google search. I have found this: [Per-User Database Authentication in Django](http://blog.everythingtastesbetterwithchilli.com/2010/02/07/per-user-database-authentication-in-django-/). I will try this. Thank you :)

Comment: Be very very wary of the caveats listed in that article. And be sure you try this out on a development copy of the database. You don't want to accidentally break your production database with unsupported database driver code! Good luck

Comment: That'd be a disaster if i'd lose data. I'll work on development server firstly, ty.

Comment: @Josh Smeaton: How was/is it unusual at that/this point in time? I think I have the same issue than OP.